# UIWebView get http status code from loaded page

Tags: ios, uiwebview, nsurlrequest

I using a `UIWebView` in a game to display a customer support form. I noticed i have problem to close the webview if the server return a 503 error (http status code sent from a load balancer)

Is there a way to easily get this http status ? can I do some setup in order to get the `didFailWithError` called when the http status code is not 200 ?

loading code

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

NSURL *nsURL = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:nsURL];

webView.opaque = YES;

webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[webView loadRequest:request];

webView.delegate = self;

closableWebViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

[closableWebViewController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];

[closableWebViewController.view addSubview:webView];

[self presentViewController:closableWebViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

this delegate method is not called

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"webview error %@",error);

 if (closableWebViewController)
 {
    NSLog(@"closing webview");
    [closableWebViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:TRUE completion:^{
        closableWebViewController = nil;
        NSLog(@"webView closed");
    }];

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily get to it but there is a good trick that is well documented here:

[How to detect and handle HTTP error codes in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236407/how-to-detect-and-handle-http-error-codes-in-uiwebview)

Comment: Yes, I checked this page but it would be nice in my situation to find a way to get the didFailWithError delegate called. I can ask my sys admin to change the way the load balancer send the error. maybe if I remove all html output from the error page it will fix the issue.

Comment: Yes that will solve it. Another option is for you to use NSUrlConnection and populate the UIView manually when it's successful.

Comment: I finally used another trick (fetching html content via javascript) but this information is obviously missing in the ios SDK.

Comment: when our server are down the load balancer return a specific html content , we are looking for that content in the html returned :  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView  {  NSString *html = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];  if ([html isEqualToString:@""] || [html containsString:@"Unavailable"]) // do something

Comment: Oh! now I understand! Yes that works. Nice when you have access to the server :)